# Express.js & Mongoose: access Object attribute name by the request parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typescript, mongoose

**The Context**

The problem is that I would like to access the attribute of an Object by the variable passed in the request made. A GET /modify/:var request is made to modify the attribute of a saved document in MongoDB. To know which attribute of the doc, converted to an Object when fetched, we would like to modify, we need the string passed in the :var.

**The Route**

```
 public modify(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction)
  {
    Model.findOne({attr: true}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        let copy = result;
        copy.attr.one.(req.params.var) = false; // here
      }
    });
  }
```

**Update**

After the answer of Paul, I edited my code and it is returning a 500 status code. I edited

```
router.put('/route/:var')

public mock(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
      Model.findOne({attr: false}, (err, doc) => {
        doc.attr[req.params.var] = false;
        model.save((e) => {
        if (e){
        console.log(e);
        }
          res.send(doc);
        });
    });
```

**The Model Structure**

```
export interface Model extends mongoose.Document {
  attr: {
             one:   {value: Boolean},
             two:   {value: Boolean},
             three: {value: Boolean},
             four:  {value: Boolean},
           };

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.  Can you try explaining better?

Comment: @Paul A GET /modify/:var request is made to modify the attribute of a saved document in MongoDB. To know which attribute of the doc, converted to an Object when fetched, we would like to modify, we need the string passed in the :var.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding yet. The Model.findOne() you're executing will find simply the first document that has an "attr" attribute set to false (if there is one).  If doc.attr is a Boolean (as it must be in your example), then you can't use bracket notation to access anything on it like doc.attr['some-string'], that will throw an error.

Comment: @Paul By the model structure given, isn't it possible to access value by doc.attr['one'].value?

Comment: It's possible, if doc.attr is an object.  If you're able to find the object by the query `{ attr:false }`, then it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first off, you should *not* be using GET requests to modify anything a GET request is just supposed to be a query, without changing anything on the server.

What you're looking for is a PUT request, which is used to modify an existing resource.

Second, you're trying to modify an object, but you don't actually have an object yet.  Your findOne has to have something to query with.  If you have a URL like `http://example.com/modify/name`  what do you expect to happen?  There's no way to tell *which* name you're modifying or what you're modifying it to.

Even if you're just doing a Boolean like you suggested, taking a given bool variable and setting it false, your URL won't tell you *which* model should have this variable set to false.

Instead, you could set it up to make a PUT request to (e.g.) `/things/:thingId` (where the thingId is a unique identifier for any given Thing you are modeling).  This would require your client to send all updateable attributes in the body of the request.

Alternately, you could set up a PUT to `/things/:thingId/:attr` if you want to allow it to modify just one attribute of the thing selected.  In that case, your handler would look something like this:

```
app.put('/things/:thingId/:attr', (req, res, next) => {
  // note, I normally do this kind of thing in an `app.param()` or `router.param()` call.  Included here for brevity.
  Thing.findById(req.params.thingId, (err, thing) => {
     thing[req.params.attr] = req.body[attr];
     thing.save((e) => {
        // todo: handle the error
        res.send(thing);
     });
  });
});
```

Callbacks are a bit more nested here than I'd normally do, as I said, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: Thank you, your general solution probably working. What I am not sure to understand is that how mongoose know that :attr will be attributed to  req.body and not req.params? In my case, there is one doc for know in the database, but I understand the general idea of searching with a provided id in the URL, and an id attribute in the model. Thus, I can use findOne(), but I am facing a 500 status response. I edited my question if you want to have a look.

Comment: Mongoose doesn't know it, Express does based on how you configure it.  req.params is populated by things that are in the URL (your url pattern /models/:attr will result in whatever is in the actual url at :attr will be placed as the value of req.params.attr.).  req.body is populated by things extracted by the body-parser module.

Comment: I'm not sure where in the code the body parser is populating the req.body

Comment: I don't have access to your code but in most express apps, you would install the body-parser module and then app.use it as middleware.

Comment: OK, but I am not sure stills how Angular can interpret that it's the second dynamic parameter that is associated with the body (get('.../:one/:two), where :one is associated with req.params and :two with req.body.

Comment: Using :attr as in your suggested solution is given a TS2304: Cannot find name 'attr'.

Comment: If you're using a GET then you won't send a body.  That's why I said use a PUT, which does have a body.  The URL parameter gives you the name of the attribute like you wanted.  So consider this, a PUT to `/model/123/lastname` with a body of "lastname=Schmoe".  `req.params.thingId` from my route example would equal '123', while `req.params.attr` would equal 'lastname'.  req.body (if you're using the `bodyParser.urlencoded` middleware) would have a key, `req.body.lastname` which equals "Schmoe".  Since it's dynamic, though, you're getting it by saying `req.body[req.params.attr]`.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have query expression error

```
Model.findOne({attr: {$exists:true}}, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        let copy = result;
        copy.attr.(req.params.var) = false; // here
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not working. The problem is really in the cop.attr.(here). The IDE can detect before compilation that the expression will produce a TS2364: Invalid left-hand side of assignment error.